# Removing accents chars from arabic text

Tags: php, mysql

I've a database with collation of utf8 / utf8_bin. DB have arabic text with accent chars (kasar etc). I want to search text without accent chars.

What i did is, i wrote 'like' query ...

```
WHERE replace(field1,0x[CODE],'') like '%[arabic text]%' --- where [CODE] is the accent char.
```

This is working fine when i write static utf arabic text in place of field1. But it does not replace when it run from database field.

May be db field have latin1 encoding. How can i fix / check this issue.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

`utf8_bin` is a binary collation - it is extremely literal and strict in comparing characters.

`utf8_general_ci` is more lenient and normalizes Umlauts and accents to their "basic" version:

`Ä` => `A`

`Ü`  => `U` etc.

I have never worked with Arabic before so I don't know whether it applies for those accents as well but I would expect so.

You should be able to temporarily use the lenient collation like this:

```
WHERE field1 like '%[arabic text]%' COLLATE utf8_general_ci;
```

Answer (score 0):

i used the below query in postgreSQL/navicat to create a new accentless column of the original accented text

---

with remove_accent_1 as (

SELECT

index,
text as original_text,
replace(replace(replace(replace(replace(replace(replace(replace(replace(replace(replace(replace(replace("text",
'ٍ',''),
'ِ',''),
'ً',''),
'َ',''),
'ّ',''),
'ْ',''),
'ۖ',''),
'ٌ',''),
'ُ',''),
'آ','ا'),
'ٰ ',''),
' ۚ ',''),
'ۗ ','')
as new_text

FROM "arabic_text"

ORDER BY "index" ASC )

select

index,
original_text,
new_text

from remove_accent_1

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).